# Module export multiple classes

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is /cars/ford.js

```
                   Ford = Car.extend({
                    classId: 'Ford',

                    init: function (driver) {
                        this._driver = driver;
                        Car.prototype.init.call(this);


                    tick: function (ctx) {
                        Car.prototype.tick.call(this, ctx);
                    },

                    destroy: function () {
                        if (this._driver !== undefined) {
                            this._driver._license.pull(this);
                        }
                        Car.prototype.destroy.call(this);
                    }
                });

if (typeof(module) !== 'undefined' && typeof(module.exports) !== 'undefined') {
                module.exports = Ford;
            }
```

This is /cars/knightrider.js:

```
                   KITT = Car.extend({
                    classId: 'KITT',

                    init: function () {
                    Car.prototype.init.call(this);
                    var self = this;
                    },


newDirection: function () {
    var self = this;

    this._move.direction()
        .duration(Math.random())
        .properties({
            x: Math.random(),
            y: Math.random(),
        })
        .voice('robotic')
        .afterDirection(function () {
            self.newDirection();
        })
        .start();


}
                });

if (typeof(module) !== 'undefined' && typeof(module.exports) !== 'undefined') {
                module.exports = KITT;
            }
```

I want to have all cars inside the same file to preserve my self sanity. How can I wrap them without altering my classes? Feel free to recommend any 'proper packaging' for Javascript functions book or tutorial, because I really dislike to open files. When I'm editing a car, I might want to edit other one.

Wish I could do:

```
        module.exports.Allmycars = KITT, Ford;
```

And then call them with:

```
        Allmycars.Ford
```

Comment: why not `module.exports.Allmycars = {KITT: KITT, Ford: Ford}` ?

Comment: Haha! It worked! I tried a lot of syntaxes like: `module.exports.Allmycars.KITT` or `module.exports.Allmycars = KITT, Ford` (just to mention two of a hundred). And I was trying to call it with Allmycars.Ford, but with that code I can call it just with `new Ford()`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be :

```
//cars/index.js

module.exports = {
  KITT:require("./knightrider"),
  Ford:require("./ford")
}
```

//So u could use :

```
var allMyCars = require("./cars");
var ford = new allMyCars.Ford();
```